# Alternative layout with moduleclass_suffix

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, overrides, module-params

I have a Problem with the carousel module from bootstrapjoomla.com
Unfortunately the module doesn't support alternative layouts.
But I need to have two carousel on my homepage. Therefore I've to create an override for the carousel where I change the carousel-id.

I tried to create an html-override depending on the moduleclass suffix but it doesn't work.
The moduleclass suffix of my second carousel is " Carousel-carousel2".
The code I inserted in the default.php in the override:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
/* Layout anhand einer CSS-Klasse im Modul umleiten */

if(preg_match('/\Carousel-([A-Za-z]+)/', $module->moduleclass_sfx , $matches)){
 if(!empty($matches[1])){
  $this->setLayout($matches[1]);#ist Layout carousel2
   echo $this->loadTemplate('default'); #carousel2_default.php wird aufgerufen
  }
}else{ 

... 

} ?>
```

carousel2_default.php is the file with my override.

My problem is, that the second carousel doesn't use the override but uses the default.php.

Comment: I solved the problem with insertign an field in the module woth the parameter "modulecarousel_id" and reinstalled it so now I can give each carousel it's own id.

Comment: Please write this as a proper answer below and mark it as "accepted" so people can easily see it has been solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add the advanced module options that allow alternative layouts, by creating an override of the modules .xml and adding the advanced fields options within the `<fields name="params">` tags, like this:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="advanced">
            <field
                name="layout"
                type="modulelayout"
                label="JFIELD_ALT_LAYOUT_LABEL"
                description="JFIELD_ALT_MODULE_LAYOUT_DESC" />
            <field
                name="moduleclass_sfx"
                type="text"
                label="COM_MODULES_FIELD_MODULECLASS_SFX_LABEL"
                description="COM_MODULES_FIELD_MODULECLASS_SFX_DESC" />
            </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

This adds the options for alternative layouts and custom module class suffix to the module settings, under the advanced tab, so you can select your alternative layout.